# arcpy.da.SearchCursor, cannot read preceding zeros from csv

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, csv, cursor

I'm using arcpy.da.SearchCursor to read a csv that has a column with preceding zeros, e.g.:

```
myCSVColumn
0124578
12598
04589
012568
...
```

When using the arcpy.da.SearchCursor it returns the value w/o the preceding zeros:

```
124578
12598
4589
12568
```

In addition, when using [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) method it returns the same result.  Does anyone know a workaround for this besides opening the csv with python and parsing through it to get the values?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar problem in the past. ArcGIS was importing columns as interger and truncating leading zeros. ArcGIS uses its own method of determining column types. I had to specifically tell ArcGIS that the attribute column was to be text by using a schema.ini file.

[This](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000) is the article I used to get started.